# Is there a way to count how many true/false outputs in a Boolean function with a for loop?

Tags: python, function, for-loop, if-statement, boolean

I am doing coursework on flight prices using Python. My Boolean function returns whether one should buy their flight ticket now or wait longer to purchase, where True indicates to buy now and False indicates to wait longer:

```
def should_I_buy(data, input_price, input_day):
    """Returns whether one should buy flight ticket now or wait longer to buy"""
    for day, price in data:
        if day < input_day:
            if price < input_price:
                return False
    return True
```

I also want to find a way to count how many True and Falses there are in the loop when I put in a random input_price and input_day.

Comment: Please update your question with some sample data and sample output.

Comment: I meant sample output for your new requirement.

Comment: Everytime the function is called it returns a boolean value, so you need to save those results somewhere, perhaps a list that you can later retrieve from?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you should use a variable that increments at each iteration:

```
def should_I_buy(data, input_price, input_day):
    """Returns whether one should buy flight ticket now or wait longer to buy"""
    number_of_false = 0
    for day, price in data:
        if day < input_day:
            if price < input_price:
                number_of_false+=1
    return number_of_false,len(data)-number_of_false
```

**NB**

Please note I have no idea what you are doing, so my answer is based on a quick look at your code.

If this doesn't behave as expected, please comment, and we can go through what you wish to obtain.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `sum` to count all True in for loop, (`True=1`, `False=0`):

```
def should_I_buy(data, input_price, input_day):
    """Returns whether one should buy flight ticket now or wait longer to buy"""
    return sum(day >= input_day or price >= input_price for day, price in data)
```

test and output:

```
data = [(14, 77.51), (13, 14.99), (12, 56.09), (11, 14.99), (10, 14.99), (9, 14.99), (8, 39.00), (7, 114.23),
        (6, 37.73), (5, 56.09), (4, 14.99), (3, 22.43), (2, 22.43), (1, 31.61), (0, 168.29)]

print(should_I_buy(data, 50.00, 8))   # output 10
print(should_I_buy(data, 18.00, 3))   # output 15
```

Hope that helps you, and comment if you have further questions. : )